# sql query to remove redundant records based on changes in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a efficient select query which will remove redundant records based on changes in column client_id, product_id, interest_rate  with min(actual_from_dt) and max(actual_to_dt) with `pk` as agrmnt_id.

```
select agrmnt_id,min(actual_from_dt),max(actual_to_dt),client_id,product_id,interest_rate from your table group by  agrmnt_id,client_id,product_id,interest_rate
```

*Source Table*

| sk | agrmnt_id | actual_from_dt | actual_to_dt | client_id | product_id | interest_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 21.02.2015 | 17.05.2015 | 20 | 345 | 4% |
| 2 | 101 | 18.05.2015 | 05.07.2015 | 20 | 345 | 4% |
| 3 | 101 | 23.08.2015 | 31.12.9999 | 20 | 345 | 4% |
| 4 | 102 | 01.01.2016 | 30.06.2016 | 25 | 333 | 3.7% |
| 5 | 102 | 01.07.2016 | 25.07.2016 | 25 | 333 | 3.7% |
| 6 | 102 | 26.07.2016 | 15.09.2016 | 25 | 333 | 3.7% |

Output

| sk | agrmnt_id | actual_from_dt | actual_to_dt | client_id | product_id | interest_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 21.02.2015 | 31.12.9999 | 20 | 345 | 4% |
| 2 | 102 | 01.01.2016 | 15.09.2016 | 25 | 333 | 3.7% |

```
|== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- == Current Plan ==
   SortAggregate(key=[agrmnt_id#4633944, client_id#4633947, product_id#4633948, interest_rate#4633949], functions=[finalmerge_min(merge min#4633975) AS min(actual_from_dt#4633945)#4633970, finalmerge_max(merge max#4633977) AS max(actual_to_dt#4633946)#4633971])
   +- Sort [agrmnt_id#4633944 ASC NULLS FIRST, client_id#4633947 ASC NULLS FIRST, product_id#4633948 ASC NULLS FIRST, interest_rate#4633949 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(agrmnt_id#4633944, client_id#4633947, product_id#4633948, interest_rate#4633949, 200), true, [id=#7017871]
         +- SortAggregate(key=[agrmnt_id#4633944, client_id#4633947, product_id#4633948, interest_rate#4633949], functions=[partial_min(actual_from_dt#4633945) AS min#4633975, partial_max(actual_to_dt#4633946) AS max#4633977])
            +- Sort [agrmnt_id#4633944 ASC NULLS FIRST, client_id#4633947 ASC NULLS FIRST, product_id#4633948 ASC NULLS FIRST, interest_rate#4633949 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
               +- FileScan csv [agrmnt_id#4633944,actual_from_dt#4633945,actual_to_dt#4633946,client_id#4633947,product_id#4633948,interest_rate#4633949] Batched: false, DataFilters: [], Format: CSV, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<agrmnt_id:string,actual_from_dt:string,actual_to_dt:string,client_id:string,product_id:str...
+- == Initial Plan ==
   SortAggregate(key=[agrmnt_id#4633944, client_id#4633947, product_id#4633948, interest_rate#4633949], functions=[finalmerge_min(merge min#4633975) AS min(actual_from_dt#4633945)#4633970, finalmerge_max(merge max#4633977) AS max(actual_to_dt#4633946)#4633971])
   +- Sort [agrmnt_id#4633944 ASC NULLS FIRST, client_id#4633947 ASC NULLS FIRST, product_id#4633948 ASC NULLS FIRST, interest_rate#4633949 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(agrmnt_id#4633944, client_id#4633947, product_id#4633948, interest_rate#4633949, 200), true, [id=#7017871]
         +- SortAggregate(key=[agrmnt_id#4633944, client_id#4633947, product_id#4633948, interest_rate#4633949], functions=[partial_min(actual_from_dt#4633945) AS min#4633975, partial_max(actual_to_dt#4633946) AS max#4633977])
            +- Sort [agrmnt_id#4633944 ASC NULLS FIRST, client_id#4633947 ASC NULLS FIRST, product_id#4633948 ASC NULLS FIRST, interest_rate#4633949 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
               +- FileScan csv [agrmnt_id#4633944,actual_from_dt#4633945,actual_to_dt#4633946,client_id#4633947,product_id#4633948,interest_rate#4633949] Batched: false, DataFilters: [], Format: CSV, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<agrmnt_id:string,actual_from_dt:string,actual_to_dt:string,client_id:string,product_id:str...
```

Comment: You have the query in your question...`select agrmnt_id,min(actual_from_dt),max(actual_to_dt),client_id,product_id,interest_rate from your table group by  agrmnt_id,client_id,product_id,interest_rate;` . I hope you have proper date datatype and not varchar one

Comment: I am trying to write the query in a more efficient way for better performance

Comment: You are not asking for performance issue, if so you should update or ask another question with the query you are trying , table description and execution plan

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN` on the query, which should give you some more information about the execution plan for the query (and show if the indexing in use is appropriate).

Comment: added the explain details

Comment: This query will not coalesce same-value rows correctly (over the time period) if the variable column values change to a different value and back. If sk=2 had interest:5% then there will be two groups with overlapping periods. Search for Islands/Gaps problems for handling these correctly.